# invalid value "(202" for "yyyy" error in generate_series() with dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to generate dynamic dates based on the current date. I want to use generate_series() to populate dates between start and end dates (interval = 1 day).

If current date is before 10/1, start date is 10/1 in previous year

If current date is after 10/1, start date is 10/1 in the current year

end date is 9/30 in year 4. For example,

current date = 5/22/2019 -> start date = 10/1/2018, end date = 9/30/2021

current date = 11/1/2019 -> start date = 10/1/2019, end date = 9/30/2022

```
select generate_series(
to_date(cast(start_date as text), 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 
to_date(concat(extract(year from to_date(cast(start_date as text), 'yyyy-mm-dd')+3),'-','09','-', 30), 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
'1 day'
) 
from (
    select case 
    when extract(month from current_date) <= 10 then concat(extract(year from current_date) -1,'-',10,'-', '01') 
    when extract(month from current_date) > 10 then  concat(extract(year from current_date),'-',10,'-', '01')
    end) as start_date
```

ERROR:  invalid value "(202" for "yyyy"

DETAIL:  Value must be an integer.

SQL state: 22007

It's complaining about year isn't integer. Which parts do I need to modify to run this query?

Comment: You might benefit from learning `date_trunc` for starters

Comment: What is the type of `start_date` and why do you cast it to text and then to a date? If it's text, not use `to_date(start_date...)` directly? If it's a date, why not use `date_trunc(start_date)` ?

Comment: If `start_date` is a string, what does it contain? I don't see any `)` in any string literal in your code so `start_date` probably doesn't contain a date

Answer (score 0):

```
select case
          when date_trunc('month', current_date) ::date < make_date(extract(year from current_date) ::int, 10, 1) then
           generate_series(make_date((extract(year from current_date) - 1) ::int, 10, 1)
                          ,make_date((extract(year from current_date) + 2) ::int, 10, 1) - 1
                          ,'1 day') ::date
          else
           generate_series(make_date(extract(year from current_date) ::int, 10, 1)
                          ,make_date((extract(year from current_date) + 3) ::int, 10, 1) - 1
                          ,'1 day') ::date
       end as dt;
```

Here In place of current_date you can use as below: current_date => '11/1/2019'::date or '05/22/2019'::date

Comment: I took the freedom to edit/format your query.(Just  grab it with the mouse-cursor and hit control-k)